# Can Windows codeless drivers be shared across architectures x86_64 and ARM64 or do they need to be separate

Tags: windows, architecture, driver, declaration

We have simple Windows codeless drivers with just some INF declarations. Can one be shared across architectures x86_64 and ARM64 or do they need to be in separate .cat instances?
The inf2cat /os: argument would include the architecture.